# Data is not being inserted into Sqlite database using Insert Query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Ive been trying to add a few items from a string array into a database and I cant seem to get the insert Query to work ive been working off of what I saw [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) Ive tried various variants of the insert query.

Here's my code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase( "Station11.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null);
    try{
        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Station ("
                + "Station_name VARCHAR);";
        db1.execSQL(query);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stations[i][0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            query = "INSERT  INTO Station VALUES ('"+stations[i][0]+"');";
            db1.execSQL(query);

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An Error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Cursor data_fetch = db1.rawQuery("Select Station_name From Station", null);

    String[] station_array = new String[data_fetch.getCount()];
    data_fetch.moveToFirst();
    i = 0;
    while (data_fetch.moveToNext()) {
        String name = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Station_name"));
        station_array[i] = name;
        i++;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "retrieved data"+station_array[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    data_fetch.close();
}
```

When i toast the retrieved data The toast says `retrieved datanull` 
I even tried inserting a string and not a variable but i still get datanull as the toast.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS This Is the String array im trying to insert:

```
stations[0][0]= "New York";
    stations[1][0]= "Boston";
    stations[2][0]= "Las Vegas";
    stations[3][0]= "Miami";
    stations[4][0]= "Chicago";
    stations[5][0]= "New England";
    stations[6][0]= "Detroit";
    stations[7][0]= "Michigan";
    stations[8][0]= "Austin";
    stations[9][0]= "New Orealns";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code missing column name after table name in insert query :

**Correct insert Query :**

```
INSERT INTO Station Station_name VALUES ('"+stations[i][0]+"');
```

**Example :**

```
INSERT INTO table_name_here (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ("Learn PHP", "John Poul", NOW());
```

Comment: I tried inserting with   `query = "INSERT  INTO Station (Station_name) VALUES ('"+stations[i][0]+"');";
                db1.execSQL(query);`   And i still get datanull as the output

Comment: Please write your column name without () 'brackets'.

Comment: You Mean Like This?        `"INSERT  INTO Station Station_name VALUES ('"+stations[i][0]+"');"`

Comment: Yes.Go for it.,

Comment: When i Used  `query = "INSERT INTO Station Station_name VALUES ('"+stations[i][0]+"');"; db1.execSQL(query); `  an Exception was thrown and the statement `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An Error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` was executed

Comment: Please let me know the exception.

Comment: `10-11 21:18:39.627 19341-19341/com.example.arun.db E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "Station_name": syntax error`

Comment: *If the column-name list after table-name is omitted then the number of values inserted into each row must be the same as the number of columns in the table.* [SQL As Understood By SQLite-INSERT](https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue derives from the use of two dimensional array:-

```
stations[0][0]= "New York";
stations[1][0]= "Boston";
stations[2][0]= "Las Vegas";
stations[3][0]= "Miami";
stations[4][0]= "Chicago";
stations[5][0]= "New England";
stations[6][0]= "Detroit";
stations[7][0]= "Michigan";
stations[8][0]= "Austin";
stations[9][0]= "New Orealns";
```

Rather use either:-

```
    String[] stations = new String[10];
    stations[0]= "New York";
    stations[1]= "Boston";
    stations[2]= "Las Vegas";
    stations[3]= "Miami";
    stations[4]= "Chicago";
    stations[5]= "New England";
    stations[6]= "Detroit";
    stations[7]= "Michigan";
    stations[8]= "Austin";
    stations[9]= "New Orealns";
```

or (*probably this one as it's more flexible*)

```
    String[] stations = new String[] {
            "New York",
            "Boston",
            "Las Vegas",
            "Miami", "Chicago",
            "New England",
            "Detroit",
            "Michigan",
            "Austin", 
            "New Orleans"
    };
```

along with :-

```
    for(i=0;i< stations.length();i++)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stations[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            query = "INSERT  INTO Station VALUES ('"+stations[i]+"');";
            db1.execSQL(query);

        }
```

Alternately the query could include the column name(s) and be:-

```
query = "INSERT  INTO Station Station_name VALUES ('"+stations[i]+"');";
```

A fully working version of you code could be :-

```
    String[] stations = new String[] {
            "New York",
            "Boston",
            "Las Vegas",
            "Miami", "Chicago",
            "New England",
            "Detroit",
            "Michigan",
            "Austin",
            "New Orleans"
    };

    int i=0;
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = openOrCreateDatabase( "Station11.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY , null);
    try{
        String query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Station ("
                + "Station_name VARCHAR);";
        db1.execSQL(query);
        Log.d("STATION_TBLCRT","Table Created");
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for(i=0;i<stations.length;i++)
        {
            Log.d("STATION_INS","Inserting station " + stations[i]);
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stations[i],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            query = "INSERT  INTO Station VALUES ('"+stations[i]+"');";
            db1.execSQL(query);

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("STATION_INSERR","Error inserting station " + stations[i]);
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An Error has occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Cursor data_fetch = db1.rawQuery("Select Station_name From Station", null);

    String[] station_array = new String[data_fetch.getCount()];
    //data_fetch.moveToFirst();
    i = 0;
    while (data_fetch.moveToNext()) {
        String name = data_fetch.getString(data_fetch.getColumnIndex("Station_name"));
        station_array[i] = name;
        Log.d("STATION_GET","Retrieved station " + station_array[i]);
        i++;
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "retrieved data"+station_array[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    data_fetch.close();
}
```

Notes!

- Toasts have been replaced with Log
- `data_fetch.moveToFirst` has been commented out as this would result in skipping the first row.
- If the above is run more than once then additional sets of stations will be added.
- the i++ in the **data_fetch** has been moved to after reporting the station (data would otherwise always be null).
- using Toasts due to duration of Toast can be misleading, hence use of Log so you can see all results.

Example output:-

```
10-14 08:16:37.446 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_TBLCRT: Table Created
10-14 08:16:37.446 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station New York
10-14 08:16:37.451 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station Boston
10-14 08:16:37.454 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station Las Vegas
10-14 08:16:37.457 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station Miami
10-14 08:16:37.461 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station Chicago
10-14 08:16:37.465 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station New England
10-14 08:16:37.468 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station Detroit
10-14 08:16:37.471 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station Michigan
10-14 08:16:37.473 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station Austin
10-14 08:16:37.478 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_INS: Inserting station New Orleans
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station New York
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station Boston
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station Las Vegas
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station Miami
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station Chicago
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station New England
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station Detroit
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station Michigan
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station Austin
10-14 08:16:37.482 22117-22117/mjt.sqlitedbexamples D/STATION_GET: Retrieved station New Orleans
```